# Syntax to add a new case to the data

Tags: spss

If i have a variable in SPSS, with name (My_Variable), label (My Variable), values(1: Yes, 2: No) etc but without data (the column in data view is empty), i want to add data using syntax! For example, i want to add a participant in 1st row, who answered "Yes", so i want 1 to be added!!! How can i do it???

I found similar questions, but the solutions refers to creating A NEW SPSS window and add the values there! But i dont want this! I want to add data in an existing variable, without creating new SPSS file!

Comment: where does that data come from ? if it is already stored in a file, perhaps you could import that file...? Please also check Stack'overflow's guide on how to ask good questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that you get the answer you need

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. If you make your research, let us know what did you find and what did you try.

Comment: The data come from my mind! (In my case is very complex to explain where the data come from, so let's say that i want a code, to add the answer 1 to the last row of an existing variable in spss!!!)!

Comment: I will use the guide next time!!! Promise!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no way to directly add cases to an SPSS dataset through syntax.
But the following seems to me pretty close - you don't create new files but you create a new dataset and add it to your original.

Let's first create a small data to demonstrate on:

```
Data list list/ID (a5) var1 var2 var3 (3f2).
begin data
"first"    1    17   7
"secnd"    5    5    12
"third"    34   11   91
end data.
dataset name originalDataset.
```

So this is your original data. Now imaging that you want to add a new case to the data, with the ID value of "hello" and the number 42 in all the columns. This is what you do:

```
* creating the new case in a separate dataset.
Data list list/ID (a5) var1 var2 var3 (3f2).
begin data
    "hello"    42    42   42
end data.
dataset name addition.
* going back to original dataset and adding the new case.
dataset activate originalDataset.
add files /file=* /file=addition.
exe.
dataset close addition.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create data in the first data set. Just create the variables and define them however you want.

```
DATASET CLOSE ALL.

INPUT PROGRAM.
NUMERIC My_Variable (F1).
VARIABLE LABELS My_Variable "I want this!".
VALUE LABELS My_Variable 1 "Yes" 2 "No".
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
DATASET NAME Empty.

DATA LIST FREE /My_Variable.
BEGIN DATA.
1 2
END DATA.

APPLY DICTIONARY /FROM Empty
 /SOURCE VARIABLES=My_Variable
 /TARGET VARIABLES=My_Variable
 /VARINFO VALLABELS=REPLACE VARLABEL.
DATASET CLOSE Empty.

FREQUENCIES VARIABLES ALL.
```

I used DATASET but you could have save the empty file to disk.
See the APPLY DICTIONARY command for more details about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using python you can add data with the `cases.append()` method

```
begin program.
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
dataset = spss.Dataset()
dataset.cases.append([1])
spss.EndDataStep()
end program.
```

Say you have 3 variables, you can assign values to each by appending the list passed to the method

```
begin program.
spss.StartDataStep()
dataset = spss.Dataset()
dataset.cases.append([1,2,3])
spss.EndDataStep()
end program.
```

Would add a case wit value 1 in the first variable, value 2 in the second variable, 3 in the third variable.

Note: the method will only work within an open datastep.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ADD FILES command.  You can also add cases with Python code.